# async_status loses results of the task it's cheking

Tags: ansible

I have these tasks to build aws ec2 instances in parallel:

```
- name: Set up testing EC2 instances
  ec2_instance:
    image_id: "{{ ami }}"
    name: "testing {{ item }}"
    tags:
      Resposible Party: neil.watson@genesys.com
      Purpose: Temporary shared VPC CICD testing
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item }}"
    wait: yes
  register: ec2_instances
  async: 7200
  poll: 0
  loop:
    - "{{ PrivateSubnet01.value }}"

- name: Wait for instance creation to complete
  async_status: jid={{ item.ansible_job_id }}
  register: ec2_jobs
  until: ec2_jobs.finished
  retries: 300
  loop: "{{ ec2_instances.results }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ ec2_instances }}"
```

The trouble is that the end debug task doesn't show what I expect. I expect to see all the return values of the [ec2_instance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_instance_module.html#return-values) module, but instead I only see:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
    changed: true
    msg: All items completed
    results:
    - _ansible_ignore_errors: null
      _ansible_item_label: subnet-0f69db3460b3391d1
      _ansible_item_result: true
      _ansible_no_log: false
      _ansible_parsed: true
      ansible_job_id: '814747228663.130'
      changed: true
      failed: false
      finished: 0
      item: subnet-0f69db3460b3391d1
      results_file: /root/.ansible_async/814747228663.130
      started: 1
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

**"Set up testing EC2 instances"** task was run asynchronously (**poll: 0**) and registered ***ec2_instances*** before they finish booting (**finished: 0**). Variable ***ec2_instances*** has not been changed afterwards. Would probably ***ec2_jobs*** ,registered after the task **"Wait for instance creation to complete"** had completed, keep the info you expect?

Answer (score 0):

So I was looking for a solution to this exact scenario as well. Couldn't find one then figured it out on my own.

Apparently ec2_instance will return the instance of an already spun up ec2 if you provide the same name, region, and image_id.

So in my case, I had to provision 3 new instances,

I ran 3 tasks each spinning up an instance, async.

Then ran 3 async_status task to make sure all 3 instances were up. Then ran

```
    community.aws.ec2_instance:
      name: "machine_1"
      region: "us-east-1"
      image_id: ami-042e8287309f5df03
    register: machine_1
```

for each of the three machines, and then stored them into my variables.